# VS 2022 ASP.Net Angular - File Not Found Errors

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2022, asp.net-core-6.0

I created a new ASP.Net Core Angular project in Visual Studio 2022 using the VS new template. Once I built the application the first time which in its turn runs npm install I see errors under the Error List VS window (please see the image below).
This is happening in one of my existing projects too.
I just wanted to confirm that this issue is not related to my current project and created the new project using the new angular template and the problem exists in here too.

I tried to add “exclude”: [“node_modules”] under tsconfig.json but that did not have any effect.

Does anyone else having this problem or knows why it is happening and how to fix it?
Thanks!

[image]